# xaml How to create a style for two tabcontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Grid>
              <Border
                 Name="Border"
                 Background="LightBlue"
                 BorderBrush="Black"
                 BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
                 CornerRadius="6,6,0,0" >
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   ContentSource="Header"
                   Margin="12,2,12,2"/>
              </Border>
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
      <TabControl Height="181" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TabItem Header="Cheese" />
        <TabItem Header="Pepperoni" />
        <TabItem Header="Mushrooms" />
      </TabControl>
      <TabControl Margin="0,201,0,60">
        <TabItem Header="Cheese" />
        <TabItem Header="Pepperoni" />
        <TabItem Header="Mushrooms" />
      </TabControl>
  </Grid>
```

That code will create two TabControls with the same style. How can I make those two TabControls use different styles? Sample code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a single style targetting "TabItem" which will apply to the tab items of any tab control, thus both your tab controls will have the same style. You can use the x:Key attribute to name two different styles and then apply them to the TabControl or TabItem as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do like in the code below,specifieing style for individual tabitems giving a key for the style resource

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="TabItemStyle1">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Grid>
             ------------
             ------------
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="TabItemStyle2">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Grid>
             ------------
             ------------
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
<Grid>
      <TabControl Height="181" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TabItem Header="Cheese" Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle1} />
        <TabItem Header="Pepperoni" Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle1} />
        <TabItem Header="Mushrooms" Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle1} />
      </TabControl>
      <TabControl Margin="0,201,0,60">
        <TabItem Header="Cheese" Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle2} />
        <TabItem Header="Pepperoni" Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle2} />
        <TabItem Header="Mushrooms" Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle2} />
      </TabControl>
  </Grid>
```

or you can use control level style resources

```
<Grid>
          <TabControl Height="181" VerticalAlignment="Top">
       <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid>
                 ------------
                 ------------
                </Grid>
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
</TabControl.Resources>
            <TabItem Header="Cheese" />
            <TabItem Header="Pepperoni" />
            <TabItem Header="Mushrooms" />
          </TabControl>
          <TabControl Margin="0,201,0,60">
 <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid>
                 ------------
                 ------------
                </Grid>
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
</TabControl.Resources>
            <TabItem Header="Cheese" />
            <TabItem Header="Pepperoni" />
            <TabItem Header="Mushrooms" />
          </TabControl>
      </Grid>
```